# Upgradable contracts - proxy storage allocation

Tags: storage, proxy-contracts

So in general, for fixed size fields, storage is **allocated** (reserved) at time of contract deployment - as per my undestanding.

Now, we deploy a `Proxy` contract, and separately a couple versions of logic contract: `V1` and `V2`.

`V1` uses storage for its `uint256 field1`. `V2` (inherits from `V1`) adds another: `uint256 field2`.

`Proxy` contract just declares an `address _implementation`, to hold the address of V1, and after an upgrade, V2.

**Question**: How **and when** is storage allocation for the proxy done?
Given that V1/V2 function calls operate on proxy storage (`delegatecall` semantics), at which point is that storage allocated for `field1`, `field2`?

The Solidity compiler has no way of knowing which versions of logic contract the Proxy will have to go through in the future. So it must be happening later at runtime.

My best guess is on-first-use, i.e. when we `delegatecall` a read/write of `V1.field1`, some kind of dynamic allocation reserves a 32-byte slot for that field.

Then once we upgrade proxy to V2 and, further, read/write `V2.field2`, another 32-byte slot is reserved in the proxy storage for that field.